# Get Facebook OAuth token and store in claims when using WebApi

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-web-api, oauth

Ive been following this blog which shows how to get additional Facebook data from a user using the scope and then storing it in claims.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates.aspx

This seems to work fine when in a standard MVC web application. However I am struggling getting  the token stored when using WebApi. The Startup.Auth code is exactly the same in my project and I can see the scope being requested is correct, but I dont understand at what point I should have access to the requested data. Also, the claim never seems to get stored which is odd.

Comment: In fact, even in the MVC web app project, the claim for the token doesnt seem to get stored, even though I am specifying this in Startup.Auth.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read my blog post about [ASP.NET Web API 2 external logins with Facebook and Google](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/) which walkthroughs you on how to integrate external logis with Web API without using MVC dependcnies or templates.

Any how if you need to get Facebook token you need to override the on `Authenticated` method and store it on custom claim so it will be available in claims dictuinatory as the code below:

```
   public class FacebookAuthProvider : FacebookAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public override Task Authenticated(FacebookAuthenticatedContext context)
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ExternalAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
```

And you call this class here in the Startup.cs:

```
 //Configure Facebook External Login
            facebookAuthOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = "xxxxxx",
                AppSecret = "xxxxxx",
                Provider = new FacebookAuthProvider()
            };
            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Any idea why the code provided by microsoft for the Startup.Auth class (OnAuthenticated => context etc) doesn't seem to get fired, even with the out of box template? It seems to store the userlogin but no claims.

Comment: I do not have answer here, but It should be working. Try my sample code and let me know your feedback.

Comment: I tried the code out of a brand new Web Project template (so to keep things simple for now). So I literally add the Facebook provider, added my keys etc and again it all works and I can see that the override method IS being hit, but it doesnt store the claim for the token. Is there something I could be missing to enable this feature?

Comment: I believe no, if my answer was helpful for you case please mark it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: @TaiseerJoudeh what about additional facebook information ?  adding context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Email", context.Email)); context.Email is null